# TXSLPageProducer code no longer works after moving from form to unit

Tags: delphi, xslt, delphi-xe2

I'm doing a XSL transform on an XML document, based on the documentation from [Bob Swart's "Delphi XE2 XML, SOAP & Web Services Development" book](http://www.ebob42.com/courseware/).
With the TXSLPageProducer on the form this works fine:

```
procedure TFrmRemoveNamespaces.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  cRemoveNSTransform =
    '<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">' +
    '<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>' +

    '<xsl:template match="/|comment()|processing-instruction()">' +
    '    <xsl:copy>' +
    '      <xsl:apply-templates/>' +
    '    </xsl:copy>' +
    '</xsl:template>' +

    '<xsl:template match="*">' +
    '    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">' +
    '      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>' +
    '    </xsl:element>' +
    '</xsl:template>' +

    '<xsl:template match="@*">' +
    '    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">' +
    '      <xsl:value-of select="."/>' +
    '    </xsl:attribute>' +
    '</xsl:template>' +

    '</xsl:stylesheet>';
// From http://wiki.tei-c.org/index.php/Remove-Namespaces.xsl
// This is a quick XSLT script for removing the namespaces from any document. It will remove the prefix as well.
var
  SS: TStringStream;
  TS: TStringList;
  XMLDoc: TXMLDocument;
  XSLPP: TXSLPageProducer;
begin
  XMLDoc := TXMLDocument.Create(self);
  XMLDoc.active := false;
  MmoAfter.Clear;
  SS := TStringStream.Create('',TEncoding.UTF8);
  SS.Position := 0;
  MmoBefore.Lines.SaveToStream(SS);
  SS.Position := 0;
  XMLDoc.LoadFromStream(SS);
  SS.Free;
  TS := TStringList.Create;
  TS.Text := cRemoveNSTransform;
  XSLPP := TXSLPageProducer.Create(self);
  XSLPP.XML := TS;
  XSLPP.XMLData := XMLDoc;
  XMLDoc.active := true;
  MmoAfter.Text := XSLPP.Content;
  TS.Free;
  XMLDoc.Free;
  XSLPP.Free;
end;
```

However, if I move the code to a class helper function in a separate unit, I get an invalid pointer operation on the "Result := XSLPP.Content".
The calling code is simply "MmoAfter.Text := TXMLHelper.RemoveNameSpaces(MmoBefore.Text);" with this code form the class helper unit:

```
class function TXMLHelper.RemoveNameSpaces(XMLString: String): String;
const
  // An XSLT script for removing the namespaces from any document. It will remove the prefix as well.
  // From http://wiki.tei-c.org/index.php/Remove-Namespaces.xsl
  cRemoveNSTransform =
    '<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">' +
    '<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>' +

    '<xsl:template match="/|comment()|processing-instruction()">' +
    '    <xsl:copy>' +
    '      <xsl:apply-templates/>' +
    '    </xsl:copy>' +
    '</xsl:template>' +

    '<xsl:template match="*">' +
    '    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">' +
    '      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>' +
    '    </xsl:element>' +
    '</xsl:template>' +

    '<xsl:template match="@*">' +
    '    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">' +
    '      <xsl:value-of select="."/>' +
    '    </xsl:attribute>' +
    '</xsl:template>' +

    '</xsl:stylesheet>';

var
  SS: TStringStream;
  TS: TStringList;
  XSLPP: TXSLPageProducer;
  XMLDoc : TXMLDocument;
begin
  XMLDoc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
  //  XMLDoc.active := true;
  SS := TStringStream.Create(XMLString,TEncoding.UTF8);
  SS.Position := 0;
  XMLDoc.LoadFromStream(SS);
  SS.Free;
  TS := TStringList.Create;
  TS.Text := cRemoveNSTransform;
  XSLPP := TXSLPageProducer.Create(nil);
  XSLPP.DOMVendor := GetDOMVendor('MSXML');
  XSLPP.XML := TS;
  XSLPP.XMLData := XMLDoc;
  // XSLPP.Active := true;
  Result := XSLPP.Content;
  TS.Free;
  XMLDoc.Free;
  XSLPP.Free;
end;
```

As you can see I had to set the DOMVendor, and the "Create(nil)" are different.
Could that last difference be the reason, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an alternate method and will use that if I can't get the above to work:

Import Type Library, Microsoft XML Parser, then 'Uses MSXML2_TLB' and:

```
class function TXMLHelper.RemoveNameSpaces(XMLString: String): String;
const
  // An XSLT script for removing the namespaces from any document. It will remove the prefix as well.
  // From http://wiki.tei-c.org/index.php/Remove-Namespaces.xsl
  cRemoveNSTransform =
    '<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">' +
    '<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>' +

    '<xsl:template match="/|comment()|processing-instruction()">' +
    '    <xsl:copy>' +
    '      <xsl:apply-templates/>' +
    '    </xsl:copy>' +
    '</xsl:template>' +

    '<xsl:template match="*">' +
    '    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">' +
    '      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>' +
    '    </xsl:element>' +
    '</xsl:template>' +

    '<xsl:template match="@*">' +
    '    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">' +
    '      <xsl:value-of select="."/>' +
    '    </xsl:attribute>' +
    '</xsl:template>' +

    '</xsl:stylesheet>';

var
  Doc, XSL: IXMLDOMdocument2;
begin
  Doc := ComsDOMDocument.Create;
  Doc.ASync := false;
  XSL := ComsDOMDocument.Create;
  XSL.ASync := false;
  try
     Doc.loadXML(XMLString);
     XSL.loadXML(cRemoveNSTransform);
     Result := Doc.TransFormNode(XSL);
  except
     on E:Exception do Result := E.Message;
  end;
end; { RemoveNameSpaces }
```

Comment: Thank you, upvoted. Just a note the `IXMLDomDocument2` is in `Winapi.msxml` (at least in xe-4, don't have xe-2 to check). Construct using `CoDomDocument.Create`

Answer (score 1):

Use it as an Interface as stated in [TXMLDocument Use Case](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE3/en/TXMLDocument_use_case_%28Delphi%29)

```
var
  XMLDoc : IXMLDocument;
begin
  XMLDoc := TXMLDocument.Create( nil );

  // your code ...

  XMLDoc := nil;
end;
```

Comment: Already tried that. It does not compile because the XMLData property expects a TComponent descendant